# How to solve SQL error: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

Any idea what is wrong with my query?

I am trying to update a row of my Database but the query I am using causes exception.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET CHANGE_DELIVERY_REASON    = 'Card Activation',
CHANGE_DELIVERY_NOTE        = 'ACTIVATION SUCCESS [1 OK - 2 OK]',
RECONCILIATION_STATUS       = 1 ,
RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = '23/4/2018 12:00:00 AM',
RECONCILIATION_COUNT        = '6',
ACTIVATION_FAILURE          = 'SUCCESS';
```

I am getting this error:

> "SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month"

I am not figuring out what is wrong with my query.

```
updateQuery = " UPDATE " + clsUtility.GetMasterTable() + " SET ";
updateQuery += "   CHANGE_DELIVERY_REASON = 'Card Activation', ";
updateQuery += "   CHANGE_DELIVERY_NOTE = '" + notes + "', ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_STATUS = 1 , ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = '" + DateTime.Today + "', ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_COUNT = '" + reconciliation_count + "',";
updateQuery += "   ACTIVATION_FAILURE = '" + resultPart + "', ";
```

Comment: Ideally, you would use *parameters* and stop mixing *data* and *code* together in a single string that then has to be pulled apart and reparsed into appropriate data types.

Comment: Learn to use parameters, rather than munging queries with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TO_DATE()` function.

Change your one line to this line:

```
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = TO_DATE('" + 
                   DateTime.Today + "', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), ";
```

**Corrected Code:**

```
updateQuery = " UPDATE " + clsUtility.GetMasterTable() + " SET ";
updateQuery += "   CHANGE_DELIVERY_REASON = 'Card Activation', ";
updateQuery += "   CHANGE_DELIVERY_NOTE = '" + notes + "', ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_STATUS = 1 , ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = TO_DATE('" + DateTime.Today + "', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), ";           //This Line is changed
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_COUNT = '" + reconciliation_count + "',";
updateQuery += "   ACTIVATION_FAILURE = '" + resultPart + "', ";
```

**General Syntax:**

The syntax for the TO_DATE function in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
TO_DATE( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language] )
```

For more info follow the link:

> https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: Am i doing it right cause i am still getting the same error   updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = TO_DATE('" + DateTime.Today + "', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), ";

Comment: You are assuming all systems will give the same output for `DateTime.Today.ToString()`...

Comment: @Lara Do not use string concatenation to make an SQL query. What happens if `notes = 'fake\', CREDIT_LIMIT = 1000000000, other_column = \'fake'`? You've just allowed someone to set a 1 billion credit limit! Use a parameterised query.

Comment: Had to use this on VS 2017 for ADO .NET connection for Oracle as was getting [ADO NET Source [2]] Error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): ORA-01843: not a valid month. Thanks. Not the same on VS 2019 where there is an Oracle Source in data flow.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the format of the date you gave, this was handled in the other answers. You will need this for other date fields, so definitely look at it.

However, for this special case, you could simply stop using your local date and let the database do the work:

```
RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = trunc(sysdate)
```

*And on a sidenote: please use parameter binding in your queries. You are wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.*

With parameter binding, you are not only save from SQL injection attacks, but also don't need to worry about format strings for data that actually does not need to be formatted for storage:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE " + clsUtility.GetMasterTable() + " SET RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = :last_updated, CHANGE_DELIVERY_NOTE = :delivery_note";

        var parameterLastUpdated = command.CreateParameter();

        parameterLastUpdated.ParameterName = ":last_updated";
        parameterLastUpdated.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
        parameterLastUpdated.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterLastUpdated.Value = DateTime.Today;

        command.Parameters.Add(parameterLastUpdated);

        var parameterDelivery = command.CreateParameter();

        parameterDelivery.ParameterName = ":delivery_note";
        parameterDelivery.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameterDelivery.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterDelivery.Value = "Some string you want in notes";

        command.Parameters.Add(parameterDelivery);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want `@param_name` in Oracle - that is SQL Server syntax - you want a colon `:` prefix instead.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your Date format

```
updateQuery = " UPDATE " + clsUtility.GetMasterTable() + " SET ";
updateQuery += "   CHANGE_DELIVERY_REASON = 'Card Activation', ";
updateQuery += "   CHANGE_DELIVERY_NOTE = '" + notes + "', ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_STATUS = 1 , ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = TO_DATE('" + DateTime.Today + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), ";
updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_COUNT = '" + reconciliation_count + "',";
updateQuery += "   ACTIVATION_FAILURE = '" + resultPart + "', ";
```

try this one

Comment: i am not hand writing my code, i am getting the Today date  updateQuery += "   RECONCILIATION_LAST_UPDATED = '" + DateTime.Today + "', ";

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4729/3 i'm tesing it in fiddle and edit it without refresh it doesn't mean i'm copy it @Nishant Gupta

Comment: Hey you no need to delete what you said if you think i'm copied you @Nishant Gupta